# Python list comprehension for double if condition

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need to clarify the list comprehension for double if statement.

```
a = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", 'mango']
c = []

# Conventional method
for b in a:
  if 'a' in b:
     if b != 'apple':
      c.append(b)
print(c)
```

The return outcomes are:

```
['banana', 'mango']
```

How could I rephrase the Python list comprehension method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either combine the codition in a single expression in list comprehension:

```py
a = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", 'mango']

c = [x for x in a if 'a' in x and x != 'apple']

print(c) # ['banana', 'mango']
```

or composite multiple list comprehension with conditional element selection:

```py
a = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", 'mango']

c = [x for x in [y for y in a if 'a' in y] if x != 'apple']

print(c) # ['banana', 'mango']
```

Comment: The nested comprehensions are no good. A *reasonable* alternative would be to use two `if` clauses.

Comment: Well, it's a language feature and Loh asked about it. Many will say that list comprehensions are more 'pythonic' than nested ifs

Comment: Hmm? No, they didn't ask for nested comprehensions. And *"comprehensions are more 'pythonic' than nested ifs"* doesn't make any sense as a reply, since my suggestion with two `if` clauses ***is*** a comprehension.

Comment: I would avoid nested comprehensions unless for the purpose of supplying values in a nested data-structure. Using the inner comprehension for this purpose is pretty inefficient. At a minimum use a generator expression for the inner stream and not create a full list that will be immediately destroyed.

Comment: In case it's not clear: I mean the same as your first solution, just with `if` instead of `and`.

Answer (score -1):

here is one way:

a = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", 'mango']

c = [b for b in a if 'a' in b and b != 'apple']

print(c)